# Rate Limiting for the Youtube Analytics Api?

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, google-api

Before i completely dive into the youtube api, i would like to know which way i should go with my Youtube Application. I am wanting to get a lot of the user's analytics information: views, earnings, likes, views per country. etc.

My question is due to rate limits, how can i do these calls if i am serving a lot of people with my application?

`1) Should i get all the info each day (Day after user joined) for each user and save that into a database (with an expiration date).`

`2) Or should i only grab the information needed at that time and store it into the database with an expiration date for each piece of data?`

Since i have never dealt with any of youtube's (or Google's for that matter) Api, i wanted to know what i was getting myself into (Api Limit wise).

What is the best way to go about getting each users data? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the "Understanding quota usage" section on [this page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports). The general recommendation is to get only what you need, but depending on the number of users you have it might make sense to request more information and make fewer requests.

I don't think there's a definite answer, depends on how many users you have  and which data you'll need.

Also, [this post](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/02/best-practices-for-avoiding-quota.html) might be useful.